# Different collations for different databases

Tags: sql-server, collation

If there is a requirement to have two different collations for two different databases what are the two options that a user has to achieve this?

Comment: This question is _very_ unclear. Please update the question with more details to explain your situation and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is to put these 2 databases onto 2 different servers so on every server the server collation will match with a database collation and there will be no collation conflicts at all.

The second option is to put them on one server so at least one database collation will be different from server collation and so you can expect surprises if the application using the database with different collation use temporary tables withou specifying the collation

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. I would like to know how exactly the two DBs can be set to have different collations while residing on the same Server as in Option 2.